# Running Tor with Ruby Watir on Mac

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, firefox

I'm trying to use Ruby Watir to open Tor on Mac.

This question [Connect to Tor-Firefox via Ruby/Watir](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/3336/3068) addresses this on Windows.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path='{location of start_tor_browser*}'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

In my case, the location would be... `Applications/TorBrowser`. But Ruby says it is not a file.

How should I do it for Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Your path should be `/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox`